# Email Marketing diferente do HTML

Tags: html, email

Estou tentando enviar um email martketing pela plataforma WEBMAIL - KINGHOST
pelo editor hmtl

porem sai muito diferente do que está no html.

abaixo o código html que está funcionando corretamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Natal InCeres 2015</title>
</head>
<body aling="center" style="background:#ffffff; text-align:center; width:100%;height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<center>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="font-size:10px; color:#494949; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; width:599px; height:50px;">Caso não esteja visualizando corretamente esta mensagem, <a style="color:#8b8b8b;" href="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/email2.html">veja on-line.</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block; background-color: #780007">
                    <tr><td widht="599" height="25" style="display:block; float: left;"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#780007" style="display:block; float:left; width: 25px; height:200px;"></td>
                        <td width="549" height="200" bgcolor="#780007">
                            <font style="display: block; float:left; width:549px; text-align: center; font-family:'Cookie', cursive; text-decoration:none; font-size:25px; color:#ffffff;">
                                A InCeres AgSystem agradece a todos os amigos, clientes e parceiros por participar conosco de mais essa jornada.<br/>
                                Desejamos a todos um Feliz Natal e que 2015 venha repleto de sonhos, conquistas e sucesso!<br/>
                                E mais uma vez estaremos ao lado de vocês dando o suporte necessário para alavancar ainda mais os seus projetos!
                            </font></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#780007" style="display:block; float:right; width: 25px; height:200px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td widht="599" height="30" style="display:block; float: left;"></td></tr>
                </table>
                <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
                <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                        <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_01.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="60" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                        <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_02.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="53" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                        <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_03.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="90" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                        <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_04.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="90" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
                </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e aqui o codigo que estou colocando no editor html do kinghost

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Natal InCeres 2015</title>
</head>
<body aling="center" style="background:#ffffff; text-align:center; width:100%;height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<center>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="font-size:10px; color:#494949; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; width:599px; height:50px;">Caso não esteja visualizando corretamente esta mensagem, <a style="color:#8b8b8b;" href="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/email2.html">veja on-line.</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block; background-color: #780007">
            <tr align="center">
                <td width="549" height="200" bgcolor="#780007">
                    <font style="display: block; float:left; width:549px; text-align: center; font-family:'Cookie', cursive; text-decoration:none; font-size:25px; color:#ffffff;">
                        <br/>  A InCeres AgSystem agradece a todos os amigos, clientes e parceiros por participar conosco de mais essa jornada.<br/>
                        Desejamos a todos um Feliz Natal e que 2015 venha repleto de sonhos, conquistas e sucesso!<br/>
                        E mais uma vez estaremos ao lado de vocês dando o suporte necessário para alavancar ainda mais os seus projetos! <br/>
                    </font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block;">
            <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_01.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="60" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_02.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="53" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_03.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="90" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" width="599px" bgcolor="#780007">
                <td><img src="http://www.inceres.com.br/emktnatal2015/imagens/img_04.jpg" alt="Natal" width="599" height="90" style="display: block; float:left;"></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tive que fazer algumas alterações por que se eu copiase o original, fica totalmente errado.

Qual o motivo dessa diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está se referindo ao alinhamento do texto, a diferença está na segunda tabela:

Código incorreto:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block; background-color: #780007">
    <tr align="center">
      <td width="549" height="200" bgcolor="#780007">
        <font style="display: block; float:left; width:549px; text-align: center; font-family:'Cookie', cursive; text-decoration:none; font-size:25px; color:#ffffff;">
          <br/>  A InCeres AgSystem agradece a todos os amigos, clientes e parceiros por participar conosco de mais essa jornada.<br/>
          Desejamos a todos um Feliz Natal e que 2015 venha repleto de sonhos, conquistas e sucesso!<br/>
          E mais uma vez estaremos ao lado de vocês dando o suporte necessário para alavancar ainda mais os seus projetos! <br/>
        </font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Código correto:

```
 <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width:599px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block; background-color: #780007">
    <tr><td widht="599" height="25" style="display:block; float: left;"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#780007" style="display:block; float:left; width: 25px; height:200px;"></td>
      <td width="549" height="200" bgcolor="#780007">
        <font style="display: block; float:left; width:549px; text-align: center; font-family:'Cookie', cursive; text-decoration:none; font-size:25px; color:#ffffff;">
          A InCeres AgSystem agradece a todos os amigos, clientes e parceiros por participar conosco de mais essa jornada.<br/>
          Desejamos a todos um Feliz Natal e que 2015 venha repleto de sonhos, conquistas e sucesso!<br/>
          E mais uma vez estaremos ao lado de vocês dando o suporte necessário para alavancar ainda mais os seus projetos!
        </font></td>
      <td bgcolor="#780007" style="display:block; float:right; width: 25px; height:200px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td widht="599" height="30" style="display:block; float: left;"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

Como você pode perceber, no código **correto** há 3 `tr` enquanto que no **incorreto** há apenas um. E como em cada um dos `tr` a mais, há um `td`, ou seja, uma coluna, essa coluna antes da coluna do texto irá deslocá-lo, fazendo com que ele fique centralizado.

Comment: como fica da maneira que você falou: http://imgur.com/UlCJTXQ

Comment: O primeiro código que você postou não seria o que estava funcionando corretamente. Entendi que já estava bom, que você precisava apenas saber qual a diferença. Olhe o código funcionando no codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyEjEd?editors=100

Comment: acho que me expressei mal, queria saber por que o codigo está funcionando no html e quando coloca para enviar pelo webmail ele desconfigura...